# Colocar separador (Guion) automáticamente en TextBox - C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Como puedo hacer para que al escribir una serie de Numero en un TextBox, este automáticamente me coloque un guion

Por ejemplo si coloco en el textbox  00726022

automáticamente ponga guion y se muestre así 00726-02-2

De antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el **control MaskedTextBox** con una máscara personalizada, para ello ve a la paleta de herramientas e inserta dicho control, posteriormente vas a la **propiedad Mask** y ahí pones la siguiente máscara:

```
00000-00-00
```

De esta forma le indicas al **MaskedTextBox** que va a tener un formato de **5** números cualesquiera, después vendría un guión **"-"**, después otros dos números, después otro guión **"-"** y finalmente otros dos números.

El uso de máscaras es importante, ya que reducen código y hacen más fácil de mantener la aplicación, puedes crear máscaras para fechas, códigos postales, matrículas de vehículos, etcétera.

Comment: Funciono perfecto, muchas gracias